# Error when deploy Vite React App with AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, vite

I tried to deploy my vite react app with AWS Amplify, but it always gives me a blank space. Here is the error in my console:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I already looked through some prompts, and already put these in my `index.html` file:

```
<script>
      // AWS Amplify needs this to work. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3673
      const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined";
      const isGlobal = () => typeof global !== "undefined";
      if (!isGlobal() && isBrowser()) {
        var global = window;
      }
  </script>
```

and in my `vite.config.js`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "./runtimeConfig": "./runtimeConfig.browser",
    },
},
})
```

I wonder how I can resolve this error. Thank you!

Comment: How are you deploying your app? Are you building it first and deploying the contents of the `dist` directory? See https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/vite/q/platform/js/#deploying-the-site-to-amplify-hosting